# How to split a string in android?

Tags: android

I am developing a program in which i am getting response from server like"1.user 2.name 3.mobile". I have to how these value in sequence. How do i spilt these value in sequence.

```
String i = "1.user 2.name 3.mobile";
```

I want it in pattern

1.user

2.name

3.mobile

Comment: if you want to split it by '.' then use i.split(".");

Comment: if you want to split as 1.User 2.user then use i.split(" ").

Comment: String[] splitArray= i.split("\\s+");

Comment: there are various way to split the string. use StringTokenizer,spit by your own style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
String i = "1.user 2.name 3.mobile";
String split[]=i.split(" ");
String firstValue=split[0];//1.user
String secondValue=split[1];//2.name
String thirdValue=split[2];//3.mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String i = "1.user 2.name 3.mobile";
        String[] array = i.split("\\s");
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(array[j]); \\ will get like 1.user 
            String[] innerArray = array[j].split("\\.");\\if you want name and sequence split through "."
            for (int k = 0; k < innerArray.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(innerArray[k]); will get like \\ 1  , user
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) function

```
String i = "1.user 2.name 3.mobile";
String[] array = i.split(" ");
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    Log.e("Tag", array[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Tested and working!
        ArrayList<String> alData=new ArrayList<>();
        String i="1.user 2.name 3.email";  
        String[] array = i.split("\\b[0-9].");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
         for(int j=1;j<array.length;j++)
           {
         //sb.append(j+1+""+array[j]+"\n ");
         alData.add(j+" "+array[j]);
         System.out.println(j+" "+array[j]);     
     }
       for(int k=0;k<alData.size();k++)
      {
      TextView tv=new TextView(mContext);
      tv.setText(alData.get(k));
      linearLayout.addView(tv);//you have to create a static linearLayout in your xml 
      }
```

Comment: I want to set it in text view in that sequence

Comment: brother you got the splitting done by using above code. Now setting it to textview in a sequence is easy.just use StringBuffer

Comment: check now. what you have to do is use sb and set it to textview after for loop

Comment: i am using like String[] array = s_szDealDescription.split("\\b[0-9].");
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
       for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
       {
        sb.append(array[j]+" ");
        m_Description.setText(array[j]);// set deal description
       }

Comment: is this correct

Comment: check my answer now.edited for you

Comment: please edit with textview

Comment: but number like 1.2. is not visible

Comment: you want number also?

Comment: yes I want like1.user  2.name 3.mobile

Comment: and also want 2.name in second paragraph

Comment: try now with new line

Comment: ravi see i have string like "1.user 2.name 3.mobile" and i want it to be in queue with number and "." but i am not getting

Comment: bro can you add the pattern you wanted in your question itself? so that i can change my answer?

Comment: see my pattern in question

Comment: check now.make sure you add a linearlayout with vertical orientation in your xml

Comment: did it do what you want?

Comment: i am only getting 4.mobile rest not getting

Comment: how many you have?

Comment: I have 1.user 2.name 3.mobile and out of these textview is only showing 3 value

Comment: can you print and show the arraylist? i mean how the value is stored in arraylist.

Comment: ok wait..............

Comment: E/CDealAppListingDetails: lIST::1 
12-23 12:52:42.027 25316-25316/com.soopermo.batterybooster.debug E/CDealAppListingDetails: lIST::2 .Click on install button in Google Play store 
12-23 12:52:42.027 25316-25316/com.soopermo.batterybooster.debug E/CDealAppListingDetails: lIST::3 .Open the app for the first time 
12-23 12:52:42.027 25316-25316/com.soopermo.batterybooster.debug E/CDealAppListingDetails: lIST::4 .Install is counted and credited

Comment: now check my answer and test

Comment: now textview is only showing 3rd vale

Comment: you are showing textview in loop i think this the problem

Comment: Paste what you written in your question

Comment: Show what you have written